# Ruby - Not sure of syntax for invoking a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am in the ruby console, and I am trying to invoke a method and I am not getting the syntax right.

Here is the structure of the file:

```
module App
  module Tools
    module Pollers
      class Kpi
        attr_reader :start_time,:stop_time

        def initialize(start_time,stop_time)
          @start_time = start_time
          @stop_time = stop_time
        end
        .....
```

and I am trying to invoke this in the console like this:

```
?> kpi = App::Tools::Pollers::Kpi.initialize(start,end_date)
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):17: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
```

Would someone be able to point me to the right syntax for invoking the initialize ?

Thanks!

Comment: Judging by the error message, the problem is elsewhere, but you'll probably want `Kpi.new`, not `Kpi.initialize`.

Comment: @minitech thank you that worked - if you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Okay, I've done that. But I don't see how you would have gotten a `SyntaxError` from that; it *should* be a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Exactly. @minitech hit it on the nose. There must have been a problem with earlier in the irb session, or this would have been `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the error message, the problem is elsewhere, but you'll probably want `Kpi.new`, not `Kpi.initialize`.

Well, apparently it's not elsewhere :)

Answer (score 7):

`initialize` is an instance method of class `Kpi`. `App::Tools::Pollers::Kpi` is a class, and can only have class methods ran on it. Ruby provides a class method for initialization to every class for free. This method is `new`. Call `new`, which takes the same arguments as your `initialize`, and returns an instance:

```
kpi = App::Tools::Pollers::Kpi.new(start,end_date)
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be

```
App::Tools::Pollers::Kpi.new(start,end_date)
```

There also seems to be a syntax error earlier in your irb session.